# How to pass two URL parameters with IIS 8.5 URL ReWrite module?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to pass two parameters in the URL with the following url rewrite rule and the page keeps showing 404 error.

Actual URL: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/?slug=view-my-class-schedul&role=56c4cfe091121c0b5b47fe66

I want to show URL on browser: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/view-my-class-schedule

Current URL Rewrite rule that's not working:

```
<rule name="KB-rewrite" enabled="true">
    <match url="^kb/article/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)&amp;role=([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="1" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="kb/article/?slug={R:1}&amp;role={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I figured it out. The display URL has to be something like:  https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/view-my-class-schedule/reader. I guess the way I was thinking is not possible.